# Java IO - Size of output file is larger than Original file

Tags: java, io

I am trying to write a read a any file and write same at different location.

```
File file=new File("<PathToFile>");
String str=FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

Writing str at diffrent location without any modification to str

```
File writefile=new File("<PathToWriteFile>");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(writefile, str);
```

Problem is that size of output file is larger than original file

EDIT:- 
I know the solution i.e read and write files byte wise, But my question is WHY this is happening?

Comment: Don't read it as `String`, read it as bytes

Comment: [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183349/pdf-file-size-is-largely-increased-when-copied-using-itext-java-library) this question, possible duplicate

Comment: If the size is changing, you most likely need to treat the file as binary. It could be your input is binary, doesn't have the encoding you expect or has `\n` instead of `\r\n`

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)

Comment: Go through the above link, readFileToString(File) is deprecated. It uses the default encoding. Try to specify encoding as: "UTF-8" in readFileToString(File fN, String encoding) and check it again once. If it succeeds it should be an encoding problem where it might be using additional bytes unnecessarily to read data.

Comment: I would suggest to use BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream())) to read data from text file and BufferedOutput for writing into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a different string encoding - there can be about X2 difference in the space occupied by each char. You can verify it using any text editor that shows the encoding (e.g. with notepad, doing "save as" without actually going through with it, will show the encoding in the "save" dialog).

As a solution, you can either

1. Read/write it as binary data
2. Use writeStringToFile(File, String, Charset) if you know the right charset